# How do I configure a kiosk on Windows 10?

Tags: windows

In certain cases, I need to set up a computer with just a few applications. This can be helpful, for example, if visitors to the company should only have access to the browser or a single program. It is important that an outsider has no access to the actual operating system.

How do I manage this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did your research tell you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has not made any effort to find out for himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Start > Settings > Accounts > Other users.
2. Select Set up a kiosk > Assigned access, and then select Get started.
3. Enter a name for the new account or choose an existing account.
4. Choose the app that will run when the kiosk account signs in. Only apps that can run above the lock screen will be available in the list of apps to choose from.
5. That's it!

Link to description: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Open Start, Settings, and in the Search Box, type KIOSK.  That brings up Kiosk Settings.  Go also to Family and other users (in Settings) and Kiosk can be set up there as well. Set it up to your requirements